# Why are this object's old values being returned after update_attributes! is successfully called in the update action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is the `update` action in `notes_controller.rb`.

```
def update
    note = current_user.notes.find(params[:id])
    note.update_attributes! params[:note]
    render json: {note: note.display}
end
```

It works fine.

My `note` object has a `datetime` field called `scheduled_time`. When the `JSON` data is returned from the `update` action on the client side, I need to know if the date that the note's updated `scheduled_time` falls on is the same as it was before the `update`.

```
def update
    note = current_user.notes.find(params[:id])
    previous_date = note.scheduled_time.to_date
    note.update_attributes! params[:note]
    date_changed = previous_date != note.scheduled_time.to_date
    render json: {note: note.display, date_changed: date_changed}
end
```

But adding this code causes the note returned in the `JSON` data (`note.display`) to contain the values from **before** the `update_attributes!`. The `update_attributes!` still works, but the `JSON` data returned from the `update` action does not reflect the update. Why would this be happening?

I'm using

```
Rails 3.2.0
ruby 1.9.3
```

I'm also using the [Memoist](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist) gem generally in the note model, but not on the `display` method specifically.

Comment: Is it possible your update is failing? Try using `update_attributes!` to see if any error is thrown, or just checking the return value of `update_attributes`.

Comment: Switch to `update_attributes!`, no error occurs. When the page is refreshed, the updated values are shown.

Comment: The previous comment may be misleading. No error occurs, meaning that the update_attributes! call is working fine, but the issue is still occurring.

Comment: Is scheduled_time an attribute that is passed in as part of params[:note]? In other words, how are you sure that scheduled_time should change with the update?

Comment: Can you show the query trace please?

Comment: Your attributes probably not added via attr_accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the assigning of the note variable and it not being updated with the result set of #update_attributes!. Do you have any hooks or observers going on?

Try using the Note object directly:

```
Note.where(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:id])
```

or if all else fails try:

```
{display: note.reload.display ... }
```

It seems to have something to do with the Memoist gem you're using but I can't be sure without diving into and simulating this.

Answer (score 0):

After your `note.update_attributes! params[:note]` try and run a `note.reload` to reload the activerelation to whatever is currently in the db